# Alternative to Picasa on Linux?

Tags: picasa, linux

I have installed Picasa on my wife's notebook (it's Ubuntu 11.04 on an HP Pavillion), but she'd like to switch to some other software (there are some issues with Picasa that bother her). She didn't like Gimp's interface (she's an artist, but not expert in digital images or photography — she's into fashion design, and the Gimp's GUI is too complex for her).

So — is there some other image editing software that is as easy and intuitive to use as Picasa? It needs to run on Linux. Preferably free, as we really can't afford anything right now.

Comment: @Jay — can you describe what your wife would like to do with the software? Picassa can be used in a lot of different ways, and knowing the specific needs would help get the best possible responses.

Comment: @mattdm: she makes collages, enhances color and brightness, crops images and does some other adjustments. These are all very easy with Picasa.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Shotwell](http://yorba.org/shotwell/).  I am/was a Picassa user, and have been pretty happy in the last few times I've used Shotwell instead.  Reasonable grouping, and a multi-level rating system, plus more upload targets, natively.

Also:

- [What tools are available for RAW image processing in Linux?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-tools-are-available-for-raw-image-processing-in-linux)
- [What photo management software would you recommend for Linux?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/321/what-photo-management-software-would-you-recommend-for-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't need to do anything super fancy in the manner that the GIMP would afford, some immediate options that come to mind are:

- [Fotoxx](http://kornelix.squarespace.com/fotoxx) which is rather obscure, but looks quite good
- [F-spot](http://f-spot.org) which is quite commonly used
- [RawTherapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/?) which I can attest is an excellent piece of software (I've used the Windows version as well).

Anyways, that's a start and they all have the requisite price tag.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape is not a bitmap, but a vector graphic program. Maybe more fun for her?